# Difference between URI and Uri in android?

Tags: android, uri

I am newbie to Android development and I am confused between the difference of URI and Uri?
Please mention the main differences.

Comment: try searching in google `difference between uri and uri android`

Comment: At least spend some time and effort searching for solutions instead of simply posting such questions.

Comment: Don't you think I did that already?

Answer (score 0):

java.net.URI is mutable

android.net.Uri is immutable

Immutable URI reference. A URI reference includes a URI and a fragment, the component of the URI following a '#'. Builds and parses URI references which conform to RFC 2396.

In the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.

More infos [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

Comment: This does not even qualify as an answer. If you really want to provide an answer to a question, I suggest you be a little more descriptive than this. Being `mutable` and `immutable` does not simply define URI and URL. There is a lot more to this that that. Please improve your answer.

Comment: This is actually the difference , it's not hard to understand. Details were added.

Comment: Initially it was just the first two lines.